# multiply and sum column on condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement

I would like to get the sum of a column, but am having trouble with a condition

```
|  Target  |  MultiOnQry  |   
---------------------------
|  50393   |       1      |
|  49      |       1      |
|  303     |       0      |
|  1934    |       1      |
|  45      |       0      |
---------------------------
```

I want to sum the truncated values from the target column, but want to multiply by X if MultiOnQry = 1.
This is being called from vba, so I will substitute X for the scalar.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Target*X AS Integer)) AS TargetSum FROM table WHERE ID = 1078
```

Comment: please provide your desired output in your question, that would help us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MultiOnQry = 0 
        then CAST(Target AS Integer)
         else CAST(Target AS Integer)*X end) AS TargetSum
 FROM table WHERE ID = 1078
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(MultiOnQry = 1, CAST(Target AS INT)*X, CAST(Target AS INT))) AS TargetSum
FROM table WHERE ID = 1078
```